# Duplicate working copies in Xcode for submodules

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I have a project with submodules, when I look under working copies, I see one of them duplicated.

This causes issues when cloning the project, xCode tries to download missing working copies and has an error from git as it tries to download the same one twice..This is happening on multiple computers,so I think it's definitely an issue with my project.

I've tried deleting my xccheckout file with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Check in your `.gitmodules` file in your working directory. Is it duplicated in there? If so, you should remove the relevant duplicate sections. I'd suggest removing the submodule then re-adding it just to be safe.

From your working directory,

```
git submodule deinit submodulename    
git rm submodulename
git rm --cached submodulename
```

Then add the submodule again.

**Edit** - another suggestion:

Try deleting `ProjectName.xcodeproj > project.xcworkspace > xcshareddata` then restarting Xcode.

Comment: It's only listed once in my .gitmodules

Comment: Try deleting `ProjectName.xcodeproj > project.xcworkspace > xcshareddata`, then re-launching Xcode.

Comment: I was able to delete those duplicates, check in and it worked fine. But my project keeps putting them there, so I set my local repo to ignore the checkout file - now the server will pull and build fine without duplicates.. I know there must be a root cause for why these keep showing up though..